# PowerShell: Unable to find Docker image locally

Tags: docker, powershell, curl, containers

I have a running container in Docker. When I try to access it via PowerShell using:

```
docker run curl -d '{ "action" : "version" }' localhost:17076
```

it says

`Unable to find image 'curl:latest' locally`

`docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for curl, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`

Though I am able to use the above function starting with `curl -d '{...` when being inside the Docker-Terminal.

The command `docker ps` within PowerShell returns `container ID` `Image` `Command` `Created` `Status` `Ports` and `Names` with the adequate information.

Is there anyone with an idea how to access the running container from PowerShell?

Comment: Docker run starts a container.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the command [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) rather than `docker run`. As in, something like the following:

```bash
docker exec -it <container_name> sh -c "curl -d '{ \`"action\`" : \`"version\`" }' localhost:17076"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but when I use the Strings outside of the curl command, it gives me an syntax error and when I am not using the Strings it says: "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"

Comment: It's possible that you need to escape some of the double quotes such as in the command `docker exec -it <container_name> sh -c "curl -d '{ \"action\" : \"version\" }' localhost:17076"`, but I can't say for sure since I don't have access to PowerShell

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Good point about `exec` and needing a container name, but to escape `"` inside a `"..."` string in PowerShell, you need `\`"`. Additionally, sadly, up to PowerShell 7.2.x, you must _additionally_ ``\``-escape `"` chars., i.e. `\\`"` (sic). However, why are you calling via `sh -c`?